# Another model for $\infty$-operads?

Tags: homotopy-theory, infinity-categories, operads

There are several well-developed notions of $\infty$-operad in the literature, which are nowadays known to be equivalent (see e.g. the introduction of [Chu-Haugseng-Heuts](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/topo.12071). However, another model is commonly in the rational homotopy theory of operads. This model resembles dendroidal Segal objects but uses a *different* indexing category of trees; I think it first appeared in [Lambrechts-Volic](http://palmer.wellesley.edu/%7Eivolic/pdf/Papers/FormalityFinal.pdf) in the cooperadic setting, but is also used in [Khoroshkin-Willwacher](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.08108.pdf) (I point this paper out since its Remark 3.5 is relevant to the question below). Let's call these *homotopy operads* for lack of a better term. Using the notion of weak equivalence for homotopy operads, we may considering the $\infty$-category of such.

> Is the $\infty$-category of homotopy operads in spaces equivalent to that of $\infty$-operads?

Homotopy operads also make sense in other categories with a notion of weak equivalence than spaces, and similarly there is a notion of enriched $\infty$-operad.

> If the answer to the previous question is yes, does it extend to an equivalence to enriched $\infty$-operads under certain conditions?

Comment: Is there a precise definition of the category you're interested in somewhere? I would guess there is a functor from the dendroidal category (or its forest version) to the category of operators of this symmetric monoidal category, but as far as I can tell both the papers you mention only give a vague description of the morphisms...

Comment: Alternatively, I suspect that inverting the "edge cutting" morphisms (as in Def 3.1 in Khoroshkin-Willwacher) should produce the symmetric monoidal envelope (or PROP) of the (coloured) operad for (1-object) operads: the objects of this envelope are sequences of corollas (and inverting edge cutting makes every tree equivalent to such an object), and the morphisms involve assembling the corollas into trees and contracting edges.

Comment: Algebras for this operad in a symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category is one correct definition of (pointed) enriched $\infty$-operads with one object/colour, so proving this localization claim would be enough to establish the comparison.

Comment: @RuneHaugseng, thank you for your comments. Unfortunately, I think those references are as precise as the literature gets. However, either of your proposed approaches might work for some precise version of their category of trees; I will think about it.